# How to set two different objFile variables?

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have code which goes through each `objFile` in a `Folder` object:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    ' do something...
Next objFile
```

Now I would like to create an inner `For Each` loop:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'do something...
    For Each objFile In AnotherFolder.Files
        'Do something else...
    Next objFile
Next objFile
```

However, I can only declare one `objFile` per script. When I try to run this, I get the following error:

> Compile error: For control variable already in use

pointing at the `For Each` line of the inner loop.

---

**Update**

I tried using two different variables, with the following code:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    ' Read creation date of file
    Set f = objFSO.GetFile(objFile)
    s = f.DateLastModified

    Dim objFile2 As Object

    ExcelPath = "C:/..."
    For Each objFile2 In ExcelPath.Files
        If InStr(s, objFile2) Then
            objFSO.CopyFile objFile, strNewFolder & "\", True
        End If
    Next objFile2
Next objFile
```

but then I get a runtime error:

> Run time error 424: Object required

again pointing at the `For Each` line of the inner loop.

How can I resolve these issues?

Comment: What is the precise error you are getting?

Comment: The error I'm gettin says "Compile error: For control variable already in use."

I know that it is never going to work the way I have it right now, because I am basically using objFile twice... My question is essentially if there is a way to 
dim another variable as an objfile or something like that?

And thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using nested loops instead of two separate loops?

Comment: Which line does the compiler point to? The code you;ve listed has two separate variables -- `objFile` and `objFile2`. Also, the error message, and the line to which it points, should be edited into your question.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, the nested second loop is referencing something from the first loop. Basically what I am doing is I have two folders and I want it to go through each item in the first folder and check if an item in the second folder matches this item.
Thank you too for your quick reply!

Comment: It points to the second objFile for loop.

Comment: Well, now that you edited the question, it's pretty obvious. You can't use the same variable for two nested loops. However, I don't think you even need nested loops. Why don't you explain exactly what you're trying to do? What do you mean by `if an item in the second folder matches this item`? Matches what exactly?

Comment: Why do you need the same variable? Use a different variable.

Comment: When I use a different variable (e.g. objFile2) I get the error message "Run time error 424: Object required". What I am trying to do is find specific files in the first folder and then check if there is a file in the second folder with the same name.
THanks again!

Comment: This is also information which you should edit into your question. As far as the error goes, are you sure `AnotherFolder` is initialized -- `Set AnotherFolder = ...`? If this is indeed the problem, then this is an entirely different error, and has no connection to multiple variables.

Comment: I have it set in the following way:
`SecondPath = "C:\pathname..."`
And then my "nested" function starts with:
`For Each objFile In SecondPath.Files`

That should work, right?

Comment: Wait. That means `ExcelPath` contains a `String`, not a `Scripting.Folder` object. A `String` doesn't have a `Files` property. You'll need to initialize with a `Folder` object -- `Set ExcelPath = objFso.GetFolder("C:\pathname...")` In order to avoid these kinds of mistakes, add a reference to the **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** library (**Tools** -> **References...**) and strongly-type your variables: `Dim ExcelPath As Scripting.Folder`

Comment: @ZevSpitz Wow I feel so stupid, that was actually the problem... Thank you so much to you and Ahmed Abdelhameed for your help!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of cleaning up the question. Does it better represent the problem you had now? Do you have any comments / suggestions / corrections?

Comment: It does represent it better. I hope maybe someone else who comes along this problem sees the solution here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To check if files in one folder exist in another folder, you don't need to compare each file in the first folder against *each file in the second folder*. You can simply concat the path and check if the file exists using `FileSystemObject.FileExists()`.

Something like this would work:

```
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object

Dim folderPath1 As String, folderPath2 As String
folderPath1 = "The\path\of\your\original\folder"
folderPath2 = "The\path\of\your\second\folder"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(folderPath1)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If oFSO.FileExists(folderPath2 & "\" & oFile.Name) Then
        ' File exists in the second folder
    End If
Next oFile
```

---

**Edit:** If you have to use nested loops for some reason, you can adapt the above code to something like this:

```
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFile2      As Object
Dim oFolder2    As Object

Dim folderPath1 As String, folderPath2 As String
folderPath1 = "The\path\of\your\original\folder"
folderPath2 = "The\path\of\your\second\folder"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(folderPath1)
Set oFolder2 = oFSO.GetFolder(folderPath2)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    For Each oFile2 In oFolder2.Files
        ' Use oFile.Name and oFile2.Name to do whatever you want.
    Next oFile2
Next oFile
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow thank your for the thorough reply! However, I cannot quite use it as I am only comparing parts of the file name. Currently my code looks like this:

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** and using early-bound types -- `Dim oFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject`. This will help avoid the OP's problem of assigning a string to a `Scripting.Folder` variable.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I used late-binding because the OP didn't show how he initializes his variables and I didn't want to confuse him more. But it's a good point.